# Empty UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have used this tutorial to put a collectionView inside a UITableView. https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

The UITableViewController is the dataSource & delegate for both the UITableView & the different collection views in each cell.
The problem is that I want to dynamically hide the CollectionView and to change its height to 0 whenever the collectionview is empty.
To do so, I have this code in CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (patients.paraclinicImage.count == 0){
    [cell.collectionView setHidden:true];
    cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = 0;
} else {
    [cell.collectionView setHidden:false];
     cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = 80;
}
```

By having this code, the collectionView shows up correctly initially. However, when scrolling fast, I will sometime have the cell load with the correct cell height, however the collection view will be empty. Refreshing the cell fixes this issue. Removing the above line of codes also fixes the issue.

Here are two images showing how the cell looks when first rendered, and after multiple scrollings (and re-renderings of the cell).

> Before scrolling issue looks like below image

[image: Before scrolling]

> But After scrolling issue seems to like below one

[image: After scrolling]
I would appreciate any ideas you guys might have.

[image: The debug view hierarchy showing an empty collectionView with an appropriate cell height]

> Debug view hierarchy showing an empty collectionView with an appropriate cell height

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the code for `UICollectionView` dataSource and delegate as well? 
I think your issue may be solved by just refreshing the collection view and not having to reload the `UITableViewCell`

Comment: did you solve the issue, if so please tell us what is the solution as I am facing the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

It is because your cell height is not updated on fast scrolling. UITableView caches the row height of indexPath just to calculate the scroll area. You need to set constraints properly and adjust the height of cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Apply the logic inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and your problem will be solved.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It still does not work.

HeightForRowAtIndexPath: returns Automatic Dimensions. 
Moreover, my current code does show the correct cell height, however, the collection view has no cells loaded. Refreshing the cell solves this problem. 
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Sometimes, my collection view inside a tableviewcell wouldn't show the collectionview cells. I solved it by calling collectionView reload on main thread. I don't exactly know the reason, as I have many background calls on each cell and was reloading the tableview on main thread itself. Still, had to reload collectionview on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    cell.colViewProperties.reloadData()
}
```